# Adding a "bursting neurons" effect to text in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, text, effects, noise

I am creating a logo with Inkscape, and would like to process the text in the logo so that it looks a bit like the "vertical lines" in this image:

[image: Raster plot of spiking neurons]

So far, after browsing all the nice effects that come with Inkscape, I only managed to arrive at this:

[image: Logo]

(The different intensities of the effect across the letters are intended, and they try to reflect the change that happens from left to right in the previous picture.)

How can I improve my logo so that the noise looks more like the first picture (little displaced dots) rather than like the current version (displaced horizontal lines)? Thank you for any suggestion.

---

In case it's relevant, the first picture is a raster plot where each row represents a neuron that is being recorded over time, and each column represents whether a neuron has fired or not at a particular instant in time.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure to check your logo scaled to small sizes. You might need to use a heavier font weight to make sure your effect is visible.

Comment: You might want to try Filters > Scatter > Pointillism. You can increase/modify the effect in the Filter Editor (Turbulence, base frequency). [See example](https://imgur.com/k8Qo5S5)

Comment: @BillyKerr thank you. Then I would still need to force the turbulence to spread only "horizontally", but at least the Pointillism effect seems like a valid starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use sprayed shapes. The next image is a stroke drawn with the sprayer tool. The selected shape is an ellipse which has been converted to path.

[image]

The settings of the sprayer are critical for good result (=good density, good amount of variation) It's probably easiest to fix a not so good stroke manually as I did. The next image shows how it's used:

[image]

1. A sample text, no fill color, converted to path
2. The preceding stroke made of ellipses, it's a group!
3. The text (1) after applying extension Generate from Path > Pattern along Path > Stretched and Repeated
4. A little more ellipses is sprayed manually over the letters

The sprayed fill must be kept thin. For some reason the text loses its readability if the weight moves off from the edges.

Warning: Inkscape gets slow with a long text and dense pattern.

Comment: Thank you, this comes close to the result I want. In case I manage to use this technique to get to the exact effect I described, I will post an update!